# CryptoJS - How to securely store the passphrase

Tags: cryptojs

I am using the javascript library https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/ to replicate and end-to-end encryption process.

What would be the best practice to keep the Passphrase secret (and not showing in the js file)?

This is my script.js file

```
// Retrieve content from the texarea
var initialCopy = $('textarea').val();
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(initialCopy, "Passphrase").toString();
```

But if I leave "Passphrase" in clear, it doesn't really make sense because from the page, you would be able to identify the encoding algorithm AES and the code?

Another option would be to request the passphrase with an Ajax call and store it into a cookie - Making sure I delete the cookie when the user logout?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to store a passphrase or a key would be by creating an .env file and installing dotenv package to access it. I am also using a .env file to store passphrase and jwt tokens.

[A reference/tutorial to use it!](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-store-secure-information-for-applications-with/)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31990061)